# Calculate % of total during drill-down

Tags: microsoft-powerbi, dax

I have a Power BI Matrix visual as shown below.
At the moment it is showing the ISO Week Number.  You can drill down to see the week ending date (not really a drill-down as it's the same level), then the monthly figure, quarterly figure and finally the annual figure.

[image]

The data table for the visual is below.
[image]

I also have a version of the table (not connected to the visual) that is below - if it makes life easier.
[image]

### Question:

I am trying to add a DAX formula to calculate the % of Temps over the total displayed (i.e taking into the account the drill-down level).
My DAX knowledge at the moment is I know there's a lot I don't know.... like most of it.

I thought I was onto something with `ALLSELECTED`, but can't figure out how to get it to sum everything - don't even know if that would be the correct starting point.
`Temp % = DIVIDE([HeadCount],CALCULATE(ALLSELECTED(HeadCount[HeadCount])))` - which is, as I thought it would, returning an error.

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

After sleeping on it for a weekend I've come up with this formula which gives me the Temp % and updates as I drill-down.

```
Temp % = DIVIDE(CALCULATE(SUM(HeadCount[HeadCount]), FILTER(HeadCount,HeadCount[Status]="Headcount - Temps")), CALCULATE(SUM(HeadCount[HeadCount]),ALL(HeadCount[Status])))
```

Unfortunately I can't get it as a third row on the Matrix table, only as a column next to the original HeadCount column - this then leaves the Perm (FTE) row blank as far as percentages go.  I've had a look around the internet and it seems that this isn't easily possible at the moment.  I'm on Version: 2.99.621.0 64-bit (November 2021), so will harass IT to update me - might be something in the newer versions.

So I've updated the formula to:

```
% = DIVIDE(SUM(HeadCount[HeadCount]), CALCULATE(SUM(HeadCount[HeadCount]),ALL(HeadCount[Status])))
```

This calculates both the Temp & Perm (FTE) percentages